# tcolorbox vertical alignment in enumerate

Tags: enumerate, tcolorbox

I'm using a tcolorbox in an enumerate. I would like the first line to be on the same baseline as the enumerate label. (In the example below, I would like the baseline of 1. and Hello to be the same.) Is there a way to achieve this?

I have tried different `box align` settings, but they seem to have no effect.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item
  \begin{tcolorbox}[box align=top, size=fbox]
    Hello
    \begin{itemize}
    \item A
    \item B
    \end{itemize}
  \end{tcolorbox}

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]